# Two edits to weird body completely messed up the question

Tags: support, questions, edits, specific-question

I am talking specifically about this question: [Two models to one viewmode with relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54969392/two-models-to-one-viewmode-with-relationship).

For some weird reason, if you remove some of the space characters, the Markdown seems to ignore the indentation:

[image]

I took some minutes in [Revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54969392/2) to remove every single white-space character and copy-paste 4 white-space characters for proper indentation.

The moment I submitted that, the OP also submitted *some* edit, but I have no idea what it was since the Revisions view is completely screwed up:

[image]

As it can be seen in the [Revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54969392/revisions), I attempted to rollback to my version, which made absolutely no difference.

Comment: The tab vs spaces debate has few winners on the tab side.

Comment: Might be too late to check now, but I wonder if triple backticks would have made it appear correct.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is either a non-standard whitespace character in the original source, or an editor preview bug. You see it when you delete the *first* space on a line, not when you delete any other spaces.

Adding four spaces to the start of the line fixes the issue (regardless of other indentation). I've re-indented the post code to clear the issue.

Note that the issue has nothing to do with other edits, you can reproduce it by [editing your 'fixed' revision #2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54969392/edit/4969d976-192d-480c-a89d-85d39b592448) and removing the first space of an indented line.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to understand why the history does not show the changes. Regardless of how the preview is rendered, I did change the amount of white-space characters in my original edit. You can see in the Revisions view that your edit was correctly saved.

Comment: There's a very good chance the asker was editing the post at the same time you were, @Camilo, and those edits got [rolled into the original revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/grace-period/info). So what ends up getting shown is the difference between the last version of the question the asker submitted and your edit (which was based on an earlier version of the same question) - thus anywhere you and the asker made the same changes, there will be no difference.

Comment: Thanks @Shog9, that makes sense.